# Log to debug module from a console application in Yii framework 2

Tags: debugging, yii2, yii-extensions

Is it possible to log to the debug module from a Yii console application? I have an application that has a web based API but also uses command line controllers for background tasks. I would like to be able to see their trace logs in the debugger. Any hints?

Comment: Does it have to be viewed from debug module? You can add `Yii::trace` in console controllers and look at the logs.

Comment: Yes, I would like to view it from the debug module to get a full picture of the application's workflow.